# Arduino wait until sim900 end response

Tags: c++, c, arduino

i am doing a GET to my server, but my code dont wait until end of SIM900 end response.
By I2C, i can see the full response of the server to the SIM900 its ok, but the Arduino dont write it correctly to the Serial.

I need to write correctly on the serial, and save it on a variable for parse it, and continued my code.

Code:

````
SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8); //ASIGANR PINES 7 Y 8 A LA VARIABLE DEL SIM900

char direccion[] = "GET /arduino/getstate.php?color=All HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: XXXXXX\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
char aux_str[50];

int respuesta;

void setup() {                                                  //configuracion
  Serial.begin(19200);
  SIM900.begin(19200);
  delay(1000);
  power_on();
  checkok();
  enviarAT("AT+CSTT=\"movistar.es\",\"MOVISTAR\",\"MOVISTAR\"", "OK", 3000); //Definimos el APN, usuario y clave a utilizar
  enviarAT("AT+CIICR", "OK", 3000);
  enviarAT("AT+CIFSR", "OK", 3000);
  enviarAT("AT+CFUN?", "+CFUN: 1", 3000); // comprueba si esta operativo =1
}

void loop() {                                                 // Programa
  enviarAT("AT+CGREG?", "+CGREG: 0,1", 3000);
  enviarAT("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"XXXXXXXXX\",\"80\"", "CONNECT OK", 5000); //Inicia una conexión TCP
    // Envíamos datos a través del TCP
  sprintf(aux_str, "AT+CIPSEND=%d", strlen(direccion));
    if (enviarAT(aux_str, ">", 10000) == 1)
    {
      enviarAT(direccion, "OK", 10000);
    }
  enviarAT("AT+CIPSHUT", "SHUT OK", 3000);  
}

void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0; //Funcion Reinicio Arduino

void checkok()//comprobar estados
{
  int i = 1;
  while ( enviarAT("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 1,1", 1000) == 0 ){
    Serial.println((String)"Intento..."+i);
    i = i +1;
    if (i == 10 ){
      Serial.println("Reiniciando...");
      delay(1000);
      resetFunc();  //Llama a reinicirar Arduino
    }
  }  
}

    // enviarAT
int enviarAT(String ATcommand, char* resp_correcta, unsigned int tiempo)
{

  int x = 0;
  bool correcto = 0;
  char respuesta[100];
  unsigned long anterior;

  memset(respuesta, '\0', 100); // Inicializa el string
  delay(100);
  while ( SIM900.available() > 0) SIM900.read(); // Limpia el buffer de entrada
  SIM900.println(ATcommand); // Envia el comando AT
  x = 0;
  anterior = millis();
  // Espera una respuesta
  do {
    // si hay datos el buffer de entrada del UART lee y comprueba la respuesta
    if (SIM900.available() != 0)
    {
        respuesta[x] = SIM900.read();
        x++;
      // Comprueba si la respuesta es correcta
      if (strstr(respuesta, resp_correcta) != NULL)
      {
        correcto = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  // Espera hasta tener una respuesta
  while ((correcto == 0) && ((millis() - anterior) < tiempo));
  Serial.println(respuesta);

  return correcto;
}

void power_on() // encender SIM900
{
  int respuesta2 = 0;
  int i= 1; //contador
  // Comprueba que el modulo SIM900 esta arrancado
  if (enviarAT("AT", "OK", 2000) == 0)  
  {
    Serial.println("Iniciando SIM...");
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    delay(1000);

    // Espera la respuesta del modulo SIM900
    while (respuesta2 == 0) {
      // Envia un comando AT cada 2 segundos y espera la respuesta
      respuesta2 = enviarAT("AT", "OK", 2000);
      SIM900.println(respuesta2);
      Serial.println((String)"Intento..."+i);
      i = i +1;
      if (i == 10 ){
        Serial.println("Reiniciando...");
        delay(2000);
        resetFunc();  //Llama a reinicirar Arduino
      }
    }
  }
  Serial.println("SIM Conectada");
  delay(2000);
}```

Arduino write like this (or nothing):
```AT+CIPSEND=88

>
GET /arduino/getstate.php?color=All HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXXX
Connection: close



SEND OK
 `⸮ɒ⸮⸮ՊHh⸮W.'
⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.1
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close```
````